# Can I make Irish Brown Bread using a covered loaf pan?

Tags: equipment, bread

Have a recipe for Irish Brown Bread that says to use a shortening pan & mentions the lid.  Would a loaf pan with foil over the top work the same way?

Comment: As someone who's eaten plenty of irish bread (and lived in Ireland) I have to say I've never heard of a shortening pan. Neither has Google! Where did this recipe come from?

Comment: Is a shortening pan like a Pullman loaf pan?

Comment: Vegetable shortening used to come in a bucket-like tin, but I doubt that what your recipe is talking about unless it's fairly old.

Answer (score 1):

The only "loaf pan with a lid" I'm familiar with is the "Pullman" pan. I have seen suggestions to use a board wrapped in foil or foil under a casserole dish set on top of a regular loaf pan if trying to emulate that form without the right pan. Foil alone would probably not hold. I don't own one and have never emulated it. I suppose if someone was using a bread pan to store grease in for use as shortening, a Pullman pan would help to keep things out of it. But as with @miken32 I can't find any reference to a pan by that name.

[image: pullman pan - image from breadtopia - no affiliation/endorsement implied.]

Comment: This was my thought.